# Delphi Intraweb website not indexed by google

Tags: delphi, indexing, intraweb

I have made a website with Intraweb and it is working in my home-server. I have a basic home.html working in a IIS where I have included  to redirect to the port 8888. 
It is working well, but google don't index misite:8888, only misite is indexed and, when I search misite in google no title or description appears.
Must I include some instructions in my Intraweb Delphi WebSite to get it.
The website is www.raizcuadrada.es, 
Thanks

Comment: you need to tell google the pages you serve, it cannot guess, you may want to switch from intraweb to something else, the website is extremely slow for it's functionality.

Comment: Did you check in Google webmaster tools? You usually get comprehensive errors there, as well as what the google bot "sees of your site". Also beware of home servers, you obviously don't have the bandwidth (it's slow...) and depending on your ISP may not be reachable 24/7 from anywhere in the world (in which case google may not be able to index it because it can't see it)

Comment: You can use SEO (Searh Engine Optimization). Try to google up SEO.

Comment: Thanks to all, I use Google Webmaster Tools to avoid these problems, but I don't improve it. About tell google the pages that I serve, I added only the root page but when I try to add the others I cann't because google read website/:8888 not website:8888 (using the option "Explore as Gooogle" in Webmaster utility using the spanish version of this utility). It is true that my bandwidth is slow, it is other issue that I am changing but I have 0 errors of tracking in the last 90 days. I think SEO in the spanish version match with "optimización" and here I have a error in the title,

Comment: ...cont, "There isn't label for title" and the keywords are not the corrects. I have title in the webpage and I don't know why google don't find it. About change Intraweb for other utility it is difficult to me because now I only know Delphi. I will continue looking for the way to solve this details, any commentary will be wellcome. Thanks again.

Comment: From looking at your web page there is nothing there for Google to crawl. It's a one page web-app. Probably will be ignored.

Comment: I dont know exactly what is a web-app. Have you some link or explanation to help me what can I add to my web to include that info that Google needs?, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

you need to adapt your IW application to be Search Engine friendly. For this, you need to use IW XI or higher and use the OnBrowserCheck event on Server Controller: http://www.atozed.com/intraweb/Blog/20110621B.EN.aspx

Check the IW XI / XII demos (SEODemo) for a sample (http://www.atozed.com/intraweb/Download/IntraWebDemos.EN.aspx)

Comment: This is the answer that I was looking for.